# How to fix columns not having matching element counts when using explode in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm attempting to separate the string contents within certain columns to separate rows. The code I'm using results in an error that states the columns do not have matching element counts. How can I fix this?

Code:

```
review_path = r'data/base_data'
review_files = glob.glob(review_path + "/test_data.csv")

review_df_list = []
for review_file in review_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(review_file)
    print(df.head())
    df["business"] = (df["business"].str.extractall(r"(?:[\s,]*)(.*?(?:Unspecified|employees|Self-employed))").groupby(level=0).agg(list))
    df["name"] = df["name"].str.split(r"\s*,\s*")
    print(df.explode(["name", "business"]))
    outPutPath = Path('data/base_data/test_data.csv')
    df.to_csv(outPutPath, index=False)
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "x", line 384, in <module>
    print(df.explode(["name", "business"]))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 8255, in explode
    raise ValueError("columns must have matching element counts")
ValueError: columns must have matching element counts
```

Comment: My question would be do you have uneven list lengths because you've failed to extract data present in your DataFrame with this regex pattern, or because there is Data missing which causes an uneven name-business relationship?

Comment: Yes it appears that some data may be missing in some cases so it won't always be 1:1. Is there a way to bypass this?

Comment: You'd need to define "bypass this". What do you want to do with the extra data? or how do you want to handle the missing? Depending on which way you look at the problem and the source of the data inconsistency.

Comment: I would like to be able to go through with splitting the contents in the cell to separate rows despite there not being matching element counts. In the event that the data is present in the 'name' column but missing from the 'business' column then I would like to output the name into a separate row while keeping the matching business value empty for that row. Is there an alternative method of coding this problem in order to do so? Such as something different from using the explode method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you have items of different lengths in one of your `name, business` series.

For instance, let's look at `business`, and assume that the content is:

```
[[1,2],
 [1,2],
 [1,2,3],
 [1,2]]
```

The third row where you have an extra value (3) than "usual" will cause the error.